# Is there a way to use the same name for both a setter method and class property?

Tags: typescript

In a typescript class, is there a way to use the same name for both a setter method and class property?  This would make setting and getting values more consistent.  For example:

```
myClass.myValue = "Hello"; //Setter.
var myValue = myClass.myValue; //Getter.

class myClass {
   myValue: string;

   myValue(inArg: string) {
      alert("inArg: " + inArg);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, and that has to do with how the class is created in javascript:

```
var MyClass = (function () {
    function MyClass() {
        this.myValue = "string";
    }
    MyClass.prototype.myValue = function (inArg) {
        alert("inArg: " + inArg);
    };
    return MyClass;
}());
```

When you then do:

```
let obj = new MyClass();
```

You create an instance of the class which has everything that exist in the prototype, including the `myValue` method, but then in the constructor you override the property `myValue` with a string.

It's similar to doing this:

```
class MyClass {
    myValue(inArg: string) {
      alert("inArg: " + inArg);
   }
}

let obj = new MyClass();
obj.myValue = "a string";
```

The only difference being that in this example you override `myValue` only for `obj` but not other instances of `MyClass`, whereas in your example it will do it for all instances because it's in the constructor.

Comment: Ok, I had seen this work in other libraries.  They must not be written in javascript.

Comment: Here is a javascript library where it works: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/

Comment: And where do they do what you say? In their samples? Or library code? if so where is it?

Comment: In the documentation for the library, samples, etc.  It works for the entire API.

Comment: I can't see in their example code anything close to what you described. Where do they have a function and a member with the same name?

Comment: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/working-with-props/index.html

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't see anything like that there.  Unless you are referring to something like this: `var map = new Map({ basemap: 'streets' });` and then `map.basemap = "topo";` ?