# Using JS Class Setter & getter along with inline functions

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-5

I'm currently trying to setup a class where the property is an array of another object (define by another class).

I'm using the set/get to manage the values. I also initialize them in the constructor.

what I want to achieve is adding inline function to this same property to make life easier overall. However, I feel like I'm using the wrong approach here.

```
class _MainObject {
    constructor(){
        this._property = [];
        this.property= {
            add(value, index){
                if (value.constructor.name !== '_SubObject'){
                    return;
                }

                this._property.splice(index, 0, value);
            },
            remove(value){
                if (value.constructor.name !== '_SubObject'){
                    return;
                }

                const index = this._property.findIndex((pId) => pId === value.id);
                this._property.splice(index, 1);
            }
        };
    }

    set property(value){
        if (Array.isArray(value)){
            value.map((el) => {
                if (el.constructor.name !== '_SubObject') return;
            });
            this._property = value;
        }
        //Tried a bunch of stuff here to assign the default object from above on the first initialization.
    }
    get property(){
        return this._property;
    }
}
```

Whenever the constructor initialize the property, it trigger the "set" and won't assign the functions to 'property' itself.

I want the actual data in obj._property but fetch by calling obj.property. I also want to be able to call obj.property.add().

This must be doable in some way and I just don't know how.

Ideally, I want to use ES5+ semantic.

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
class Property {
    constructor(){
        this.value = [1,2,3];
    }

    add(x){
        this.value = [...this.value, x]
    }
}

class _MainObject {
    constructor(){
        this._property = new Property();
    }

    set property(value){
        if (Array.isArray(value)){
            this._property = value;
        }
    }
    get property(){
        return this._property;
    }

}

const a = new _MainObject()
console.log(a.property)
a.property.add(4)
console.log(a.property)
```

You need to wrap property into it's own class.

This is the only way to do this as you cannot have a getter and a function or property of the same name as explained here:

[Is there a way to use the same name for both a setter method and class property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38860239/is-there-a-way-to-use-the-same-name-for-both-a-setter-method-and-class-property)

[Differentiate between property and method with same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29435891/differentiate-between-property-and-method-with-same-name)

[Can JS have getters and setters methods named same as property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19531845/can-js-have-getters-and-setters-methods-named-same-as-property)

[Function and variable with the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057649/function-and-variable-with-the-same-name)

Comment: Thanks. Will take a look tonight anf accept it if it works